# Raspberry | Rasbian update php and apache

Tags: php

I'm using Rasbian VERSION=`"8 (jessie)" Linux raspberrypi 4.14.73-v7+` which the Apache/2.4.10 PHP 5.6.38-0+deb8u1 has been installed.

How can I upgrade the PHP package to **PHP 7.3** that is compatible with Apache or Nginx version?
Also, I don't want to do `sudo upgrade` because the system has a lot of old packages in which the system does not have enough space and it will be broken.

**Update** with info from comment:
I would like to build a new sd card with Raspbian Buster, but I do not have physical access to the device, only ssh.

Comment: Jessie is out of date. Build a new sd card with Raspbian Buster.

Comment: @CoderMike This is what I wanted to do, but I do not have physical access to the device. Only ssh

Comment: Sounds like it needs a larger sd card anyway. Why have you only got ssh access?

Comment: @CoderMike The device is not in my city. And I need to install the latest version of laravel lumen on it. And for it need php> = 7.3. 32 gb flash drive

Comment: Did you test [THIS](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-7-3-on-debian-9-debian-8/) link?

Comment: You don't need to do `sudo upgrade`.

Comment: To get from Jessie to Buster using the not recommended upgrade path you should go to Stretch first then Buster. It can be done over an ssh session (but you may get problems if you get disconnected). Start by editing files in /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list change `jessie` to `stretch`. Run `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade`. Reboot, reconnect then edit the sources from `stretch` to `buster`. It's risky but it will get Apache2 with PHP7.3.

Comment: @Dougie I bet it will not work, in particular with only remote access.

Comment: @Ingo I updated a few of my headless Raspberries at home that way. The "get out of jail free" being I could pull the SDCard and fix it in another RPi.   User7752471 could  build a new SDCard at home then mail it to someone at the remote location to do a shutdown, swap, reboot on the remote RPi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a new SD Card with Raspbian Buster is the right way I would also do it. All other things doing only remotely on a deprecated Raspbian version **Jessie** it too risky. You risk to lose connection or have a system that isn't working anymore. I would build and test the new SD Card with Buster at home and send it to the remote place so someone there can just swap the SD Card. If it doesn't work you can always revert to the running system. Even better is to configure a complete second Raspberry Pi at home and send it to the remote place.